# Taking my husband and son on tourist visa while I am going on business visa

Tags: visas, uk

I will be travelling to the UK on a business visa. I want to take my husband and son along with me on tourist visas. What should my husband's visa application mention in accommodation? Can he say that he will be staying with me at my office-provided accommodation? Also, should he mention any accommodation costs? What should he write in living expenses?

The site I'm using is visa4uk

Comment: You don't mention what nation you are coming from ???

Comment: @JoeBlow Irrelevant, OP obviously requires a visa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making a business trip to the UK and will stay in corporate housing, you want your husband and child to accompany you...

> Can he mention that he will be staying with me at my office provided
>   accommodation?

Yes, if he is staying in corporate housing provided by your employer, he should write it down.

> Also, should he mention any accommodation costs?

If there are no accommodation costs that he will bear, then he should 0, otherwise he should report what he expects to pay.

> What should he write in living expenses?

He should calculate the expenses that he will pay and put the result on his application.

Other notes

- He should put your GWF number in the remarks section of his
  application. Same with your child.
- Make sure the company agrees that extra guests will stay at their
  housing, *especially* if there are children involved.
- If he claims to be employed, then he should submit bank statements
  per
  [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)
- For similar types of questions, use the *natural meaning of the
  words* to formulate an answer. There are no 'trick' questions on the
  form and they all can be answered in absolute terms.

Comment: Should I submit all documents in original or xerox copies would do. I understand that bank statements need to be original, also employment letter. My husband's business registration certificate and his name change affidavit -do these need to be submitted in original as well?

Comment: Also my child's birth certificate?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. All the required evidence should be submitted.

Comment: Hi Gayot Fow........will photocopies do or I need to submit originals?

Comment: Our site discourages raising new questions in the comments because it prevents exposure for future readers and dilutes the value of the site's archives. So I must encourage you to use the 'Ask Question' button, there's no penalty for asking questions all day as long as they are topical. Got it? OK, then for this time, use originals where you have them.